# difficult use of Tapestry zones - changed ids

Tags: jquery, css, tapestry

There are some problems appearing when I use tapestry 5.3.6, CSS, jQuery (using tapestry5-jquery 3.3.3) javaScript.

When I set a page that has zones (I am using jQueryUI tabs) and then switch from one to another refreshing some components I have made, some elements loose their style due to changed tag IDs. I fixed that with embedded styles, but have another problem now.

I have binded some events to some elements by using jQuery. After zone switching some elements looses its events. I have solved it with events binding inside onActivate function. Also, there are problems with jQuery selectors when ids of elements changes, but it could be solved with conditional selectors.

Is there a more elegant way to couple with this kind of problems in tapestry? What I have now is very confusing and bring more complexity to my project.

Comment: I am using [jquery.tabs](http://tapestry5-jquery.com/components/docsjquerytabs) component which make its own zone.

Answer (score 0):

provided your zones are not created within loops, you can set both the `t:id` and the `id` of the zone to be equal:

`<t:zone t:id="myId" id="myId" />`

this will stop tapestry assigning a new Id when the zone is updated.

Comment: It does not work in my case because I am using [jquery.tabs](http://tapestry5-jquery.com/components/docsjquerytabs) component which has its own zone. I don't know if I can change its id as you have suggested.

Comment: that sounds like a tapestry-jquery bug, but if it's just the styles you are worried about why not apply styles using class names instead of ids?

Comment: class names were allready given, and it would be even more dirty to add more classnames by using jQuery on page load.

Comment: "then there's no pleasing you" ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to solve my problem by turning t:ajax flag off from component [ajax.tabs](http://tapestry5-jquery.com/components/docsjquerytabs) which would exclude usage of zones. As it seems that solved my problem, but the question remains open because I would maby want ajax behaviour to be turned on in some other case.